# How to use less than < and greater than > symbols in metamug XML

Tags: sql, xml, metamug

How to use less than "<" and greater than ">" symbols in metamug XML in the resource file and SQL console

```
select * 
from tbl_reservation 
where fare > 100 
  and fare < 50000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly `<` and `>` works in SQL console

With `<` `>`
[image: With]

Without `<` `>`
[image: Without]

But to use them in `resource` file you'll have to escape them as per the below table
[image]
For more [as per these guideline](https://metamug.com/docs/resource-file.php#xml-escape-characters)
So your query will be

```
select * from tbl_reservation where fare lt 100 and fare gt 50000
```

Answer (score 4):

you should use [XML Escape Characters](https://metamug.com/docs/resource-file.php#xml-escape-characters):

So,

```
select * from tbl_reservation where fare gt 100 and fare lt 50000
```